# Get selected checkbox(dynamically created) value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following **code snippet** for create a **dynamic checkbox**.

This **code snippet** is inside of the `for loop`.based on the `for loop` the **check boxes** will create.The main function is called in the `html` onload.

This functionality is working fine.But if I choose the **check box** I need to get the value of the **check box**.I use the `addEventListener` its not working fine.

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.name = "name";
  checkbox.value = teamIds;
  checkbox.id = i;
  checkbox.addEventListener("click",setTeamIdsinTextBox(teamNamesToShow),false);
  body.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Now I need, if I select the two **checkboxes** and I want to pass the both values to the **`setTeamIdsinTextBox function`** with comma separate string.

How can I do this? I need to achieve this with the **javascript** alone.

so I need to frame the selected checkbox values like

> **var teamNamesToShow ="firstselectedcheckboxvalue,secondselectedcheckboxvalue"**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: All form controls have a *form* property that references the form they're in, so `this.form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')` should get the checkboxes. Now iterate over them and collect the values of the checked ones (use Array *filter* method perhaps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click listener needs to iterate over the checkboxes and collect the ids of those that are checked. You can use a selector to get just the checked ones, or filter the checked ones later which allows for a less complex selector.

The following uses the more complex selector but simpler *map* callback:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var form = document.forms['form0'];
 
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.name = 'name' + i;
    checkbox.value = 'value' + i;
    checkbox.id = 'cb' + i;
    checkbox.addEventListener("click",
                              setTeamIdsinTextBox,
                              false);
    form.appendChild(checkbox); // add checkboxes to form, not body
  }
}

function setTeamIdsinTextBox() {
  var form = this.form;
  var cbs = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'));
  var ids = cbs.map(function(cb) {return cb.id});
  form.ta0.value = ids.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<form id="form0">
  <textarea id="ta0" name="ta0"></textarea>
</form>
```

The body of the function could be:

```
this.form.ta0.value =  Array.from(this.form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')).map(function(cb) {return cb.id}).join(', ');
```

but I think splitting it over a couple of lines is more sensible.

#### Edit

*Array.from* was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 so may not be available in all implementations in use. There's a [polyfill at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) that can be included to provide support where lacking. Also, it can be replaced with *Array.prototype.slice*, which has ubiquitous support.

Instead of:

```
Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'));
```

use:

```
[].slice.call(form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'));
```

however that may fail in IE 8 as (from memory) it doesn't allow calling built–in methods with a host object as *this*. In that case, go directly to *map* and provide a [polyfill for IE 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
[].map.call(form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function(cb) {return cb.id});
```

That will work in IE 8 as the polyfill for *map* means that it's a native function, not built–in so using a NodeList as *this* is OK. Versions of IE with *map* are OK with the host object thing.

Comment: @RoboG I got the following error Object doesn't support property or method 'from'

Comment: @User—that means your host doesn't support Array.from. There's a [*polyfill on MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) you can use, or replace with `[].slice.call(this.form.querySelectorAll(...)).map(...)...`.

Comment: @RoboG can you please little bit elaborate  on this .?

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop which you are iterating maintain an int variable which gives you the exact no. of checkboxes which you are going to create.And then using that again iterate through a for loop for that int variable and check for each checkbox whether it is checked or not.

```
int countCheckBox=0;
var listOfCheckBoxVal='';

function setTeamIdsinTextBox(){

    for(int i =1; i<=countCheckBox;i++){

    if(document.getElementById(i).checked==true){

          listOfCheckBoxVal += document.getElementById(i).value+",";

    }

}
```

Now this listOfCheckBoxVal  variable will have the list of values of checked checkboxes seperated by a comma.